# Reparentable Master Detail option of custom field in patch release

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, custom-field, master-detail, patch

I have a custom field in my managed package with "Reparentable Master Detail" option as unchecked. I want to enable this option. Is it possible to do the same with PATCH release of my package?
I know patch release has few limitations but not sure about this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following changes are possible after the package is Released:

> 1. Label
> 2. Description
> 3. Length (increase or decrease)
> 4. Precision (decimal
>      places)
> 5. Scale Required or Not Required
> 6. Cascade Delete checkbox
> 7. Sharing Restricted Delete (Lookup)
> 8. **Re-parentable Master Detail checkbox**
> 9. Picklist strictly enforced
>      checkbox
> 10. Formula field text
> 11. Related List Label
> 12. Summary Filter
> 13. Help
>       Text
> 14. Mask Type
> 15. Mask Character
> 16. External Data Entity
> 17. Lookup Filter
>       Options
> 18. Auto Number Display Format
> 19. Field Default Value

Same things applied to patch orgs also. There is no difference. Changes in patch org never reflect in main release org.